# Spring 3.1 DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver override/disable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

After upgrading to Spring 3.1 I noticed that my custom SimpleMappingExceptionResolver is no longer handling missing request parameter exceptions(MissingServletRequestParameterException) and other 'default' exceptions.  Instead Spring's DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver is swallowing the exceptions and returning a 400 error.

I'd like to allow my custom exception resolver to continue resolving all exceptions.  I'm not sure how to about doing this(whether to disable or override the DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver with a no op resolver).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each resolver has an 'order' property.  This can be used to adjust the precedence of resolvers relative to one another.  By increasing the precendence of my resolver(lower order) it will be invoked before Spring's default exception resolver.

Comment: Worth noting that you probably want to use Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE (or some offset from that) for the order value so that your resolver has a high enough priority to be run.